# Execution failed for Task :@react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED'. React-native

Tags: android, xcode, react-native, npm, react-native-community-netinfo

My react native project fails to build app and gives this error:

```
Task :@react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 3s
10 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 9 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

It doesn't install app on the emulator device.

Here is the package.json content:

"dependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.6.3",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.7.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"aadhaar-validator": "^1.1.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-pure-class-to-function": "^1.0.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
"compare-versions": "^3.6.0",
"frisbee": "^1.1.7",
"libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.52",
"mobx": "^4.9.4",
"mobx-react": "^6.1.4",
"react": "^16.8.1",
"react-native": "^0.59.10",
"react-native-appstore-version-checker": "^2.7.2",
"react-native-calendar": "^0.13.1",
"react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
"react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.1",
"react-native-config": "^0.11.7",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
"react-native-element": "^1.2.1",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
"react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
"react-native-material-kit": "0.5.1",
"react-native-phone-input": "^0.1.10",
"react-native-push-notification": "^7.2.3",
"react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
"react-native-simple-toast": "^0.1.1",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-style-tachyons": "^4.0.0",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
"react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
"react-native-version-number": "^0.3.6",
"react-native-webview": "7.5.2",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
"@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.2.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
"@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
"@types/react": "^16.9.5",
"autobind-decorator": "^1.3.4",
"axios": "^0.15.3",
"babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
"babel-jest": "18.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
"babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
"bluebird": "^3.5.0",
"concurrently": "^3.1.0",
"eslint": "^3.14.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^3.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0",
"flow-bin": "0.33.0",
"jest": "18.1.0",
"jetifier": "^1.6.4",
"json2csv": "^3.7.3",
"markdown-toc": "^1.1.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
"nodemon": "^1.11.0",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"tslint": "^4.3.1",
"typescript": "^3.6.4"
},

Please suggest any hints to rectify this error.

My project used to run fine few weeks back. It is giving errors now, without any changes made to code.

Comment: Try to set targetSdk to 31 in app/build.gradle

Comment: It gave the same error even after setting targetSdkVersion to 31.